# Retrieve article object including its image using the Shopify JavaScript Buy SDK custom query

Tags: javascript, shopify, shopify-javascript-buy-sdk

I'm using the shopify-buy SDK to try and fetch the articles off of my Shopify store  just using JavaScript on the frontend, following the "Expanding the SDK" directions here: https://shopify.github.io/js-buy-sdk/#expanding-the-sdk.

Using the code below, I am able to retrieve my articles and *some* of the fields that I need.

```
// Build a custom query using the unoptimized version of the SDK
const articlesQuery = client.graphQLClient.query((root) => {
  root.addConnection('articles', {args: {first: 10}}, (article) => {
    article.add('title')
    article.add('handle')
    article.add('url')
    article.add('contentHtml')
  })
})

// Call the send method with the custom query
client.graphQLClient.send(articlesQuery).then(({model, data}) => {
  console.log('articles data')
  console.log(data)
})
```

However, I really need to pull the featured image for each article as well, and unfortunately, when I add the line `article.add('image')` in my articlesQuery, the resulting articles data logs `null`. I tried building a custom productsQuery, and that has a similiar problem - I can retrieve some of the product fields, but when I try add the line `product.add('images')`, I just get `null` back from the storefront API.

Does anyone have experience building custom/expanded queries and successfully retrieving images?

Comment: can you add the output of `console.log(data)` ?

Comment: did you try `img`? if returning null, either articles don't have image or property name you're trying to access does not exist. You found anywhere correct keyword to retrieve images or was adding `image` to your article was your idea?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Thanks to Rebecca Friedman on the js-buy-sdk repo's github issues section for providing this working solution:

```
const articlesQuery = client.graphQLClient.query((root) => {
  root.addConnection('articles', {args: {first: 10}}, (article) => {
    article.add('title')
    article.add('handle')
    article.add('url')
    article.add('contentHtml')
    article.addField('image', {}, (image) => {
      image.add('id')
      image.add('originalSrc')
    })
  })
})

// Call the send method with the custom query
client.graphQLClient.send(articlesQuery).then(({model, data}) => {
  console.log('articles data')
  console.log(data) // works!
})
```

Because the [image](https://help.shopify.com/en/api/custom-storefronts/storefront-api/reference/object/article#image) field is its own object, you have to add a callback function to specify the fields you need.

Answer (score 1):

Try following:

```
// Fetch all products in your shop
client.graphQLClient.fetchAll().then((acticles) => {
  console.log(acticles);
});
```

And then check in console what sort of available property names your articles have. If SDK allows you get any image data, there should be for sure anything like `imageSrc` ||  `imageUrl`  || `img`......